# C++ Language Parsing and Logical Operators's Short-Circuit

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, logical-operators

When it comes to the short-circuit of the logical operators, according to the Standard in 7.6.14 e 7.6.15 (N4868).

> 7.6.14 Logical AND operator
>
> [...] the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is false.

> 7.6.15 Logical OR operator
>
> [...] the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand evaluates to true.

When this implementation is discussed in Logical Operators Chaining as (Cond1 && Cond2 && Cond3), in my interpretation, the presented is different from my **current mental model** on how the c++ code parsing/operator binding occurs in **compiler-time**.

For something as

```
if (cond1 && cond2 && cond3) {
   //something
}
```

It is understood as **"if cond1 is false, so occurs short-circuit, cond2 and cond3 are not evaluated and the expression is false"**.

For me, even if you have the same result, a more accurate expression about how the parsing should works is **"The first 'AND' operation is an sub-expression of the second. If cond1 is false, so occurs short-circuit, cond2 is not evaluated and the sub-expression is evaluated to false. Then in the second operation occurs short-circuit, cond3 is not evaluated and this expression is also evaluted to false".**

Like:

> (cond1 && cond2) && cond3 : evaluation of cond1 and short-circuit of
> sub-expression to false (cond2 is not evaluated)
>
> false && cond3 : short-circuit of the full-expression to false (cond3 is not evaluated)

---

I am worrying about the model in an high level language like C ++ and not the implementation in runtime (the implementations of the compilers seem to be exactly the same as the first expression I showed, if cond1 is false occurs a jump).

**The interpretation I did is accurate, pedantic or is incorrect and is inappropriate in this context (It is overthinking)?**

Comment: @isaactfa Actually, the `&&` operator has left-to-right associativity, so it is parsed as `(cond1 && cond2) && cond3`. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: @AdrianMole That's my bad, thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Manuel, can you explain how an evaluation of `cond1 && (cond2 && cond3)` breaks your mental model?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. Both statements are correct. One is just a bit more detailed than the other. It is not clear to me what "_It is understood as_" is referring to exactly. What does "_When this implementation is discussed in Logical Operators Chaining_" refer to? There is no section in the standard with that heading.

Comment: Note that order of precedence of operators is not evaluation order. I think you are mixing them.

Comment: @jxh  In this case it's ok, if cond1 is false the second operation is not evaluated because it is an operand of the first AND. What causes me strangeness is when the first AND is operand of the second. For me, the value of the first expression (cond1 && cond2) would be the operand of the second expression as a prvalue like: (false && cond3), as happens in Arithmetic Operation like 2 + 2 + 2 = (2 + 2) + 2 = 4 + 2 = 6. Because of the short circuit, the conclusion that if cond1 is false, so the full-expression is false seems not to follow the same parsing as other binary operations

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry I mean short-circuit

Comment: @user17732522 This more detailed form of parsing is accurate, then? This is what made sense to me but was not sure because the explanations were similar to the first

Comment: The C language is defining a behavior of the logical operators that was adopted by the language inventors. Normally, logical operators would be commutative. But in the C language, they are not. In terms of using associativity with parentheses to understand left to right vs. right to left associativity, associating `(cond1 && cond2)` still leads to the correct answer.

Comment: @Manuel As I said, I don't see anything wrong with either. What is confusing to me is that you keep referring to someone/something giving you a different explanation/interpretation without saying what that is. What is "_the explanations_" in "_because the explanations were similar to the first_" referring to? What explanations?

Comment: @user17732522 That the parsing of an expression like (cond1 && cond2 && cond3) is "If cond1 is false, then the (full-)expression is false", suggesting for me that the parsing of the compiler does not treat (cond1 && cond2) as an operand of the cond3 and that the short-circuit is in the (full-)expression. For my model, the short-circuit conceptually should be in the sub-expression and then in the full-expression. The results are the same and only the expression cond1 is evaluated in both, but it's an model more precise (I think). English is not my first language (thanks for the patience).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct as far as compiler's "mental model" and whoever wrote "if `cond1` is false, so the full-expression is `false`" is correct as far as CPU's "mental model" in this specific case.

On the compiler side, parsing `cond1 && cond2 && cond3` results in (using clang `-ast-dump`)

```
`-BinaryOperator 0x557a79f02230 <col:1, col:19> 'bool' '&&'
  |-BinaryOperator 0x557a79f021d8 <col:1, col:10> 'bool' '&&'
  | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x557a79f021a8 <col:1> 'bool' <LValueToRValue>
  | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x557a79f02168 <col:1> 'bool' lvalue Var 0x557a79f01da0 'cond1' 'bool'
  | `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x557a79f021c0 <col:10> 'bool' <LValueToRValue>
  |   `-DeclRefExpr 0x557a79f02188 <col:10> 'bool' lvalue Var 0x557a79f01ec8 'cond2' 'bool'
  `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x557a79f02218 <col:19> 'bool' <LValueToRValue>
    `-DeclRefExpr 0x557a79f021f8 <col:19> 'bool' lvalue Var 0x557a79f01fa8 'cond3' 'bool'
```

evaluation of this tree starts at the root `&&` at column 19, which must first evaluate its lhs: so it walks down to the `&&` at column 10, which must first evaluate its lhs too: so it walks down to `cond1`. If that returned `false`, the col:10 `&&` returns `false` also, without visiting the rhs branch, and then the col:19 `&&` also returns `false` without visiting the rhs branch.

Both gcc and clang as I just tested produced runtime code that is the equivalent of

```
if (cond1 == false) goto done;
if (cond2 == false) goto done;
if (cond3 == false) goto done;
 return true;
done:
 return false;
```

So this evaluation is an example of a (very simple) compiler optimization

see https://godbolt.org/z/rYc11PvPb for the AST and the compiled code